# Website checkout not working in latest version of Chrome/Firefox; Apache SSL Cipher issue

Tags: apache, magento, centos, cpanel, whm

I am facing an issue with apache configuration for the last few days. I have rebuild apache more than 50 times to fix the issue but the issue still exist. The problem seems to be with the apache cipher suite used. The issue exists with the latest google chrome/Firefox browsers. I have already enabled TLS version on the server and also tried disabling SSLv2 and SSLv3 on server but this didn't work. Please see the apache ciphers used. Please see that i have already followed the main troubleshooting articles below but the issue is still their.

1) http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-disable-sslv3-and-protect-your-whmcpanel-server-from-poodle/

2) https://poodle.io/servers.html

Also please see the Apache ciphers used below.

ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA
:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA

Please help me in fixing this. Thanks in advance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
#ssl.conf   
 SSLHonorCipherOrder on
 SSLProtocol -ALL -SSLv3 +TLSv1
 SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:!EXPORT
```

Here is snapshot of my site which using above configuration.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Mohit, Thanks for your reply. I have added the mentioned apache configuration changes but still have issue. I have checked the website on SSL LAB checker and please see the screenshots of the difference in configuration of a working and non-working website.

Working : http://image.prntscr.com/image/58a4cddacaea4f8c865978fd6ec6f179.png

Not-working : http://image.prntscr.com/image/889215c2689744e99bcaab2cee302d15.png

Thanks

Comment: Dear Sandeep, In such case we would required your apache ssl configuration to review.

Comment: Dear Mohit, Do i need to make any changes to SSL ciphers mentioned above. This is the ciphers already used.

Comment: Dear Sandeep, Trust me with given configuration you will disabling SSLv2 and SSLv3 on your server. And I have used most common ciphers.

Answer (score 1):

```
#ssl.conf   
     SSLHonorCipherOrder on
     SSLProtocol -ALL -SSLv3 +TLSv1
     SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:!EXPORT:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384: DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA: ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA :!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA

# add all required ciphers in existing configuration would please test this
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the above issue after reinstalling the SSL certificate. I   used the same certificate, Key and bundle for reinstallation. Thankyou for your help.

Thanks